# Let $f$ be a differentiable function with no point $x$ such that $f(x)=0=f'(x)$ show that $f$ has finitely many zeros.

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

Let $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function. Assume there is no
point $x$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0 = f'(x)$. Show that $f$ has only a finite
number of zeros in $[0, 1]$.

My proof. Assume otherwise. Keep bisecting the interval choosing the subinterval with infinitely many zeros. (This is fairly. standard so I won't go into it). We obtain $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n$. Moreover, $x_n\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. We see immediately that $f(x)=0$. Our goal is to show $f'(x)=0$ as well. We know,

$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)}{h}=L
$$

There's a subsequence $x_{n_k}$, $h_k = x_{n_k}-x\ge 0$, (if not we will use $x-x_{n_k}$ and the proof will be similar) and we observe for every $h$, there's $N$ such that if $k\ge N$, $h_k=x_{n_k}-x\le h$.

Thus we observe,

$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{f(x+h_k)}{h_k}=L=0
$$

The last part is due to the fact $f(x+h_k)=0$. Contradiction!

I am only looking for proof verification. $\textbf{Please only provide hints if my proof is wrong. Complete solutions won't benefit me at all!}$

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is fine, but you write things in a cumbersome way. You can write your limit as
$$
\lim_{z\to x}\frac{f(z)}{z-x}=L. 
$$
Since the limit exists, you can also take the limit along any sequence that converges to $x$; in particular your $x_n$. Thus
$$
L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)}{x_n-x}=0. 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just started learning real analysis so my writings tend to be cumbersome

Comment: Don't worry about it. It takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I prefer constructive proofs, here is one in case you are interested:

Let $Z = \{ x \in [0,1] | f(x) = 0 \}$. Note that $Z$ is compact since $f$ is continuous.

If $x \in Z$ then $f'(x) \neq 0$ and so there is some open interval $I_x$ containing $x$ such that $I_x \cap Z = \{x\}$.

The $\{I_x\}_{x \in Z}$ form an open cover of $Z$ hence there is a finite subcover. Hence
$Z$ is finite.

Comment: I don't understand why $Z$ is finite just because there's a finite subcover

Comment: If there is a finite subcover $I_{x_1},...,I_{x_m}$ then we have $Z \cap (I_{x_1}\cup \cdots \cup I_{x_m} ) = Z = \{x_1,...,x_m \}$.

Comment: Thank you! This is a new technique I've never seen before